# cannot open linker script file libgcc_s.so.1: Too many open files

Tags: ubuntu, linker, arm, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to cross compile glibc 2.16 for ARM on a x86_64 machine running ubuntu 12.04.
I am using the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi toolchain from the repository.
configured with:

```
 ../glibc-2.16.0/configure --build=arm-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/arm/include/ --prefix=/usr/arm
```

when i run make i hit this error:

> /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:
>   cannot find libgcc_s.so.1 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

location of libgcc_s.so

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/libgcc_s.so
```

creating a symlink to libgcc_s.so.1 in the same folder causes this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/libgcc_s.so.1: Too many open files
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any ideas what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a broken toolchain, i completely removed and purged all arm-linux related files and re-installed the toolchain and libs and now it works again.

Comment: Exactly the same here. My error was to stop the make command then restart it leaving the build directory inconsistent. Removing it worked. Thanks for sharing.